# Google form upload + attach the uploaded pdf in an Auto email reply

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm currently doing a project where I have users fill up a simple form of Name, Email address and upload a single pdf.

When form is submitted, the destination GSheet of that form takes in Name, Email address and the URL of the uploaded PDF. After form submission, I am able to do an auto reply with an email with html that says "Received your form submission with the attached file." But is it possible to attach that uploaded pdf in that email just using the URL?  I am not able to find a ClassDrive for GetFileByURL. Only could find getfilebyname/type.

I can think of another way which is to have the user manually put in the name of the file being uploaded in the form and have the google app script to getfilebyname. I am trying to avoid human error however. Human error like name of the file uploaded and the filename typed in the form does not match. :)

```
    function onSubmit(e) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var range = e.range
      var row = Number(range.getRow());
    
      var upFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ADDRESS OF WHERE THE UPLOADED FILE FROM THE FORM IS");
    
      var formReceived = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML Email"); //get the html template
    
      var parent_name = ss.getRange('B'+row).getValue();
      var parent_email = ss.getRange('C'+row).getValue();
      var fileURL = ss.getRange('D'+row).getValue();
    
      ss.getRange('E'+row).setValue("Error! Email not sent.");
    
      //Tag input into the html
      formReceived.parent_name=parent_name
    
    //Once the form is submitted, the URL will show up on the Gsheet
    //in column D. Is there a way to attach the file from that URL into the mailapp below.
   //Not using the line below (getfilesbyname).

        var invoicereceipt = upFolder.getFilesByName("Can be manual input from form");
    
        if(invoicereceipt.hasNext()){
          MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: parent_email,
          name: parent_name,
          htmlBody : formReceived.evaluate().getContent(),
          attachments: [invoicereceipt.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
          });
            var now = new Date()
            var k = Utilities.formatDate(now,'GMT+8',"YYYY.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
            ws.getRange('E'+index).setValue(k); 
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But is it possible to attach that uploaded pdf in that email just using the URL? I am not able to find a ClassDrive for GetFileByURL. Only could find getfilebyname/type.`. Can I ask you about your current issue of your script and your goal? And, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a working script.
Goal: User submit a google form with 3 inputs. Name, Email address, pdf upload.
> Destination to a google sheet, with 3 columns. Name, Email address, URL of the uploaded pdf.
> An automated email will be sent to the email address with email body "Received" + attached in that email is the uploaded pdf that was submitted via the form.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: A Google form has 3 questions: Name, Email address, upload a file. When a user submitted the form and uploaded a pdf file, I need the Google app script to automatically send an email to the email address and attach the pdf file that was uploaded. I have also edit my original post with the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to send an email when the Google Form is submitted. At this time, you want to attach the uploaded PDF file to the email.
- Your script is existing in Google Spreadsheet linked with Google Form.
- Your function of `onSubmit` is installed as the OnSubmit installable trigger.

#### Modification points:

- The email title is not included. In this case, an error occurs.
- `ws`, `index` are not declared.
- In this case, I thought that the event object can be used.

When these points are reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  var [, parent_name, parent_email, fileURL] = e.values;
  var formReceived = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML Email");
  formReceived.parent_name = parent_name;
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    subject: "sample mail",
    to: parent_email,
    name: parent_name,
    htmlBody: formReceived.evaluate().getContent(),
    attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById(fileURL.split("=").pop())],
  });

  // e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("Error! Email not sent."); // I'm not sure whether you want to use this line.
}
```

- The uploaded PDF file is retrieved by `DriveApp.getFileById(fileURL.split("=").pop())`.
- **In this case, please delete the installable OnSubmit trigger and reinstall it again. By this, the additional scopes are included.**

#### Note:

- This is a simple modified script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you very much for the reply and the assist! Yes it works! I would like to understand more on this line [DriveApp.getFileById(fileURL.split("=").pop())].
What does the split("=") and pop() do?

Comment: @dracomagmus Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, when the file is uploaded, the URL is like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`. `fileURL.split("=").pop()` retrieves `###` from the URL. The URL is splitted by `split("=")`. By this, it's `["https://drive.google.com/open?id", "###"]`. From this, `###` is retrieved by `pop()`. `pop()` is used for retrieving the last element from array. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) If this was not useful, I apologize.